# AB testing measuring time window-based metrics

Tags: experiment-design

When conducting AB testing for time window-based metrics (usually for a subscription type of business), we usually measure user X day revenue since conversion (subscribed), eg. user 60-day revenue since subscription starts. Subscription start is the point of conversion.

If an AB test if at upper funnel before user converted (subscribed), and we want to measure user revenue impact, is it better to measure user 60 day revenue since experiment enrollment or since subscription starts?

Example: If we conduct an email campaign with control have no discount, test group has 10% discount to incentivize user to subscribe, for user time-based revenue, should we measure user 60-day revenue from experiment enrollment (receiving email) or from user starts subscription?

If the email campaign with discount only pulls user conversion time forward and does not increase their subscription lifetime, would measuring this metric based on point of experiment enrollment bias the result?

Comment: What is the hypothesis?  That the email will cause more revenue per user?

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes, that is correct.